# HTML's form action using wordpress plugins?

Tags: wordpress

function theme_options_panel(){
       add_menu_page('ss title', 'Social Share', 'manage_options', 'theme-options', 'ss_callback');

```
   }
   add_action('admin_menu', 'theme_options_panel');
```

function ss_callback(){

```
   $html .='<form action="index.php/wp-content/plugins/social_media/ss_query.php" method="post">';
   $html .= '<br> <br>';        
   $html .= '<p class="description">';
   $html .= 'Upload your social link  here.';
   $html .= '</p>';
   $html .= 'Facebook:'.'<input type="URL" name="fb" value="" />';
   $html .=  '</br>';
   $html .= 'Twitter:'.'<input type="URL"  name="tw" value=""  />';
   $html .=  '</br>';
   $html .= 'Linkedin:' . '<input type="URL"   name="lin" value="" />';  
   $html .=  '</br>';   
   $html .= '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">';
   $html .= '</form>';

   echo $html;


}
```

Comment: What is the question? what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You should not send data to a PHP file in your plugin, you will not be able to use WordPress core functions there.

So the solution is to use a hook.

Put an hidden field in your form, it should be unique. For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="unique_hidden_field" value="1">
```

You don't need the action any more, just let it submit to the current page:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

And the PHP code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'process_post' );

function process_post() {
     if( isset( $_POST['unique_hidden_field'] ) ) {
          //You code goes here
          //You can use $_POST['fb']
     }
}
```

Hope that helps!